# iOS Swift Cannot acces EXIF data on stored photo

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I need to get location of the pics in the device photo gallery. To do so I am trying to load the Exif data of the image.
This is my code:

```
   import ImageIO

   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
       let ciImage = CIImage(image: image!)
       let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(ciImage as! CGImageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary?
       if let dict = imageProperties as? [String: Any] {
        print(dict)
    }
  }
```

When I try to run my code on the device, the App crash.
I think the problem is in the cast, I tried to do some manipulaiton, but I am not able to convert my `UIImage` in `CFImageSource` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `CIImage` (nor a `UIImage`) to a `CGImageSource`. To create a `CGImageSource` do:

```
guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 1)
    else { fatalError("Error getting image data") }

guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)
    else { fatalError("Error creating image source") }

let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
```

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` returns the image as a JPEG image so it doesn't matter what format `uiImage` originally is in.